# Alamofire: Is there so kind of notification like AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification?

Tags: swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I wanted to log every network request made with Alamofire. I've previously used `AFNetworking` where I did the same thing using the `AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification`

So is there a way to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire does not post any notifications; however, since Alamofire is open source you can add this yourself.

All requests are funneled through the `request` method of `Request.swift` (currently line 210). You can just add a line to this method which logs whatever information you need.

```
public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {
    print("Started request: \(URLRequest.URLRequest)")
    ....
```